# Firebase Cloud Function, getting a 304 error

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have a firebase cloud function that resets a number under every user's UID every day back to `0`. I have about 600 users and so far it's been working perfectly fine.

But today, it's giving me a `304` error and not reseting the value. Here is a screenshot:

[image]

And here is the function code:

```
export const resetDailyQuestsCount = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  const ref = db.ref('users');

  ref.once('value').then(snap => {
    snap.forEach(item => {
      const uid = item.child('uid').val();
      ref.child(uid).update({ dailyQuestsCount: 0 }).catch(err => {
        res.status(500).send(err);
      });
    });
  }).catch(err => {
    res.status(500).send(err);
  })

  res.status(200).send('daily quest count reset');
})
```

Could this be my userbase growing too large? I doubt it, 600 is not that big.

Any help would be really appreciated! This is really affecting my users.

Answer (score 1):

An HTTP function must only send a single response to the client.  This means a single call to `send()`.  Your function can possibly attempt to send multiple responses to the client in the even that there are multiple updates that fail.  Your logging isn't complete enough to demonstrate this, but it's a very real possibility with what you've shown.

Also bear in mind that this function is very much **not scalable** since it reads **all** of your users prior to processing them.  For large number of users, this presents memory problems.  You should look into ways to limit the number of nodes read by your query in order to prevent future problems.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. About limited the number of nodes read -- how would this work? Every user's node needs to be updated.

Comment: Maybe update only those nodes that need to be updated?  Those that actually have dailyQuestsCount > 0?